# PDF of the exp-gamma distribution

Tags: density-function, gamma-distribution

exp-gamma distribution is defined as the density of the random variable log(X) when X is a gamma random variable.

I am trying to obtain its PDF. Unfortunaltely, the only formula I have found is from a link on wikipedia toward [Wolfram page for that distribution](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ExpGammaDistribution.html) and their formula is not the same as the one I obtain myself.
They say that

> "The exp-gamma distribution is mathematically defined to be the
> distribution that models $Y=log(X)$ whenever X $\sim$
> GammaDistribution. "

So I suppose we are considering the same thing.

Here is their formula :

[image]

First of all there is a $\mu$ location parameter that is not in the Gamma distribution as presented in Wikipedia. But, Wolfram presents a more general gamma family with two additional parameters that they name GammaDistribution[α,β,γ,μ]. They explain :

> GammaDistribution[α,β] (which is equivalent to
> GammaDistribution[α,β,1,0]) is often referred to as "the" gamma
> distribution.

So I will take 0 for $\mu$

Now, my calculus is as follows  :

$f$ the PDF of $X$ is such that $f(x) = K.x^{k-1}e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}}$

with $Y=ln(X)$ we have $dx=e^ydy$

If $g$ is the PDF of $Y$ We must have $g(y)dy=f(x)dx = f(e^y)e^ydy$

So

$$g(y)=Ke^{-\frac{e^y}{\theta}+ky}$$

which is not the same formula as Wolfram's if you look carefully ...

Any idea ?

Comment: I see no difference: simply substitute $(x-\mu)/\theta$ for your $y$ to obtain the Wolfram expression.  Where do you think you have erred?

Comment: Why should I have the right to do such substitution ? Furthermore, doing so, I do not get exactly the Wolfram formula due to the $\theta$ already in $\frac{e^y}{\theta}$

Comment: (1) That "right" is a basic rule of arithmetic: equal expressions can be substituted within free variables in other expressions.  (2) That factor of $1/\theta$ is explained at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4220.  Maybe that thread addresses what is actually bothering you?

Comment: Sorry I do my best to understand. I suppose you are right and that I don't see something obvious. But I am perplex. X is a Gamma random variable and Y=log(X) is another one. Both Wolfram and I are calculating the PDF of Y. I name y the values of Y while Wolfram names them x. But there is no difference, just 2 names for the same thing. We should have found exactly the same PDF function.

Comment: Furthermore, your substitution provides $g(y)=Ke^{-\frac{e^\frac{x-\mu}{\theta}}{\theta}+k\frac{x-\mu}{\theta}}$ it is not the Worlfram formula.

Comment: The factor of $1/\Gamma(k)$ is the normalization factor that you have written "$K.$"  Again, there is no apparent difference between what you obtained and the Wolfram value apart from the notation.

Comment: I have no problem with the normalization coefficient. My idea so far is that Wolfram formula is the PDF for $\theta Y + \mu$ not $Y$. But also, that there is maybe a mistake in their formula. I am going to reedit my question with that suggestion.

Comment: You will first want to learn about location-scale families of distributions.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/265939, for instance.  That will help you see there is no mistake.

Comment: I am very sorry for that misunderstanding :-) 
Let my try a last time to defend my point. 
You told me "substitute (x−μ)/θ for your y to obtain the Wolfram expression.". 
I did it and obtained the formula that you can see 4 comments above this one. 
1) Is my substitution correct ?
2) If yes, is it the same as Wolfram's formula, even if you substitute $K$ by something ? (notice $\theta$ appears 3 times within the first level exponential while only 2 times in Worlfram's formula)
By the way the link in your previous comment is very interesting.