# Mathematical Definition of Parameters

Tags: beta-distribution, identifiability, shape-parameter

I am currently trying to differentiate the parameters in the beta generalized Gompertz distribution by [Benkhelifa](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0307904X17304134) which has the following CDF
[image]

and the following PDF
[image]

with all parameters being larger than zero. When graphing the functions I can't clearly differentiate which are the shape, scale, and location parameters.
[image]

I know that the original beta distribution has a and b as shape parameters, is it correct to say that it will also be shape parameters in this distribution? Does anybody have an idea on how to differentiate between the types of parameters? Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly is your question..?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/49794/919 answers the scale parameter question: clearly, $1/\lambda$ is a scale parameter.  The others are shape parameters.  https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/266046/919 shows you how to identify scale and location parameters.

Comment: @Tim I know that the original beta distribution has a and b as shape parameters, is it correct to say that it will also be shape parameters in this distribution? Does anybody have an idea on how to differentiate between the types of parameters?